# Correct MVC in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter project I have a Login controller that load this view:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class = "menu-item" data-target="../indoamericana/soporte/callSupport/"> Mis solicitudes </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The controller: `soporte`, function: `callSupport`

```
public function callSupport($index = null, $order = null){
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('session_user');
    $data['solicitud']  = $this->helpdesk_model->getRequest($session_data['usuario'], $index, $order); 
    $data['categories'] = $this->helpdesk_model->getCategories();
    $this->load->view('modules/help_desk/supports', $data);
}
```

With jQuery I call the controller and render in a page content that is a `<div>` element:

```
$(".sub-menu .menu-item, .module-item").click(function(event) {
    $(".page-content").load($(this).data('target'));  
    $("title").text( $( this ).text() );
});
```

In the view 'modules/help_desk/supports':

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="admin-support" data-target="soporte/callSupport/"> 
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Estado <a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-sort" data-sort="status"></i></a></th>
    <th>Prioridad <a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-sort" data-sort="priority"></i></a></th>
    <th>Responsable <a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-sort" data-sort="id_responsible"></i></a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($solicitud as $key => $value) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="label label-sm <?= $value['label']?> "><?= ucfirst($value['status']) ?></span></td>
        <td><span class="badge <?= $value['class']?> "><?= $value['priority'] ?></span></td>
        <td><?= $value['name'].' '.$value['last_name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php  } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, in the first `<td>` a put an anchor tag calls another controller with jQuery similar than before. Please be critical, very severe with me.

Comment: If you are lucky, you'll never have a help desk employee called `<script>alert(123)</script>`. I wouldn't count on that, though. Better protect your code against cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

## General comments

I don't see much wrong with the code. The biggest concern I might have is that PHP code is mixed in with the HTML - an alternative to this would be using a template system. CodeIgniter has the [template parser class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html) which should allow you to do this.

> *Please be critical, very severe with me.*

Okay - I am not typically this critical but you asked for it! The next section has a couple other review points

## Minor nitpicks

In the PHP code, `$data` is not declared before values are assigned to specific keys:

> ```
> $data['solicitud']  = $this->helpdesk_model->getRequest($session_data['usuario'], $index, $order);
> ```

I don't see a problem with this practice but [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) advises against it:

> If `$arr` doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This practice is however discouraged because if `$arr` already contains some value (e.g. [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and `[]` may actually stand for [string access operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). It is always better to initialize a variable by a direct assignment.

---

I tried running the jQuery callback through [the demo page on eslint.org](https://eslint.org/demo/#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). It showed this warning:

> 'event' is defined but never used.

For this line:

> ```
> $(".sub-menu .menu-item, .module-item").click(function(event) {
> ```

While `event` could be used if necessary, it isn't needed.